# Find timespent Brightcove embed code in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, brightcove

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://players.brightcove.net/5785763993001/default_default/index.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative; display: block; max-width: 960px;">
<div id="myPlayer" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe
    id="brightcove-iframe"
    src="https://players.brightcove.net/5785763993001/default_default/index.html?videoId=6336141823112"
    allowfullscreen=""
    allow="encrypted-media"
    style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var player;

// Initialize the Brightcove player
videojs("myPlayer", {}, function () {
  player = this;

  // Add event listeners to track play, pause, and ended events
  player.on("play", function () {
    alert('Video is playing');
  });

  player.on("pause", function () {
    alert('Video is paused');
  });

  player.on("ended", function () {
    alert('Video has ended');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm attempting to embed a Brightcove video player within an iframe, and I want to capture events like play and pause in order to track the amount of time viewers spend watching the video. I've successfully obtained the var player object, but I'm encountering difficulties when trying to implement event handling for these actions.
I am not enter in the play function.It seems play and pause function is not working.I expect that when I click the play button, it will provide information about the amount of time I've spent watching the video.

Comment: `videojs` works with HTML5 `video` elements - not what you got here to play your video, you got an iframe. _Inside_ that iframe, a `video` element might get used again - but you don't have direct access to it from your code, because the iframe content is loaded from a different domain. You will need to check with Brightcove to see if they offer any dedicated JS SDK for this, that allows you to communicate with their player.